# How do I change a primary key value in SubSonic 3.0?

Tags: c#, subsonic, primary-key

Is it possible to update a primary key after it's been created in SubSonic 3.0??

Consider this MySql table:

```
create table items (  
Type varchar(30) NOT NULL,  
Attribute varchar(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

And I am trying to edit an item object (so called row)

```
item i = item.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Attribute == "123");  
i.Attribute = "234";
i.Save();
```

The above snippet throws a syntax error MySQLException. After profiling the same, the query that was being executed at back end was this:

```
UPDATE ITEMS WHERE ATTRIBUTE="123";
```

Any suggestions/help please.